# Insert same UUID into two tables (once as primary key, once as foreign key) in one statement

Tags: postgresql

Consider the postgres view which joins together two tables `table_geom` and `table_data` by the field `id_data` (`id_data` being the primary key of `table_data` and a foreign key in `table_geom`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myschema.view AS 
 SELECT table_geom.geom, table_geom.id_geom, table_geom.id_data,
        table_data.id_data, table_data.data
 FROM myschema.table_geom, myschema.table_data
 WHERE table_geom.id_data = table_data.id_data;
```

`id_geom` and `id_data` are UUIDs. I'd like to autogenerate them on insert using `uuid_generate_v4()` with a rule such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE view_insert_rule AS
  ON INSERT TO myschema.view DO INSTEAD (
    INSERT INTO myschema.table_geom (geom, id_geom, id_data) VALUES (new.geom, (select uuid_generate_v4()), $ID_DATA$);
    INSERT INTO myschema.table_data (id_data, data) VALUES ($ID_DATA$, new.data);
  );
```

**Problem**: `$ID_DATA$` needs to be the same UUID when inserting into the two tables.

One attempt was

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE view_insert_rule AS
  ON INSERT TO myschema.view DO INSTEAD (
    WITH ins_data as (
      INSERT INTO myschema.table_data (id_data, data) VALUES ((select uuid_generate_v4()), new.data) RETURNING id_data
    )
    INSERT INTO myschema.table_geom (geom, id_geom, id_data) VALUES (new.geom, (select uuid_generate_v4()), ins_data.id_data);
  );
```

which however does not work due to `ERROR:  cannot refer to NEW within WITH query`.

Any idea how write such an insert rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing an `INSERT` on a view, the recommended procedure is an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view. In the trigger function you rewrite the insert on the view into two inserts on the underlying tables:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_new_uuids() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  new_id uuid;
BEGIN
  new_id := uuid_generate_v4();
  INSERT INTO myschema.table_data (id_data, data) VALUES (new_id, NEW.data);
  INSERT INTO myschema.table_geom (geom, id_geom, id_data) VALUES (NEW.geom, uuid_generate_v4(), new_id);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ins_view
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON myschema."view"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_new_uuids();
```